# Magento 2 Equivalent for Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)

Tags: magento2, app

I'm using following code:-

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)

Same code I want to use for Magento2, how can I achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
$this->storeManager->setCurrentStore(0);
```

Where $this->storeManage is an instance of **Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface**

Ex:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and converting Mage_Core_Model_App :: ADMIN_STORE_ID to magento 2